# Dynamically include modules in another module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to dynamically include all modules within a certain folder into this other module. My code is as follows:

```
module Extensions
  module ProductExtension
    def add_included_extensions
      extensions = Pathname.glob("lib/extensions/merchant/*.rb")
        .map(&:basename)
        .collect{|x| 
          x.to_s.gsub(".rb", "")
          .titleize.gsub(" ","")
        }

      extensions.each do |merchant|
        include "Extensions::MerchantExtensions::#{merchant}".constantize
      end
    end
    def add_items
      add_included_extensions
      Merchant.all.each do |merchant|
        send("add_#{merchant.name.downcase}_items")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However it doesn't seem to be actually including the files because when I call the send method, it says the method it's calling doesn't exist. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have only fast look - you use `titleize` instead `camelize`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is you include your modules inside instance methods, so they are not included in the class.

Try:

```
self.class.send(:include, "Extensions::MerchantExtensions::#{merchant}".constantize)
```